# Groupby no numerical values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: CustomerID, product code, MonthNumber, Units purchased. I can have for the same customer more than a product for the same month number.
I need to obtain as in the picture a table with MonthNumber as column and in the cells a string composed by # of units +  Product code.
Any suggestions?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO5GK.jpg)

Comment: You need a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @F.Valle, did the below solution help? If so, feel free to accept (green tick on left).

Answer (score 0):

This is one method via `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'ECM ID': [3448, 3448, 3448, 3448],
                   'Mnt': [1, 6, 3, 5],
                   'Code': ['FUP', 'FUP', 'OSO', 'PRD'],
                   'N': [1, 2, 2, 1]})

df['Code'] = df['N'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Code']

d  = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str))

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row['ECM ID']][row['Mnt']] = row['Code']

res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

for col in (set(range(res.columns.min(), res.columns.max())) - set(res.columns)):
    res[col] = ''

res = res.sort_index(axis=1)

#           1 2      3 4      5      6
# 3448  1-FUP    2-OSO    1-PRD  2-FUP
```